# How do i discover My Bluetooth Device and add the list to my Listview in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, bluetooth

I am writing a android program to pair and communicate with the BLUETOOTH hardware. I am able to switch ON and OFF the Bluetooth device... But i am not able to search the Bluetooth devices on range and store or display(I am new to android and java).
I could not understand the code in developer.android.com .
So i am posting here... Please help.. Thank u.

HERE IS MY CODE..

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        if (!((Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1)).isChecked()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),
                        "Bluetooth IS  switched ON now...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),
                        "Bluetooth IS  switched OFF now...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                ((Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1)).setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: see this link: http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-discover-and.html